# How to access a pandas dataframe by string?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a lot of dataframe that have similar names for example:

```
NB_2014= pd.read_csv("E:/NB_2014.CSV", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')
NB_2015= pd.read_csv("E:/NB_2015.CSV", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')
NB_2016= pd.read_csv("E:/NB_2016.CSV", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')
NB_2017= pd.read_csv("E:/NB_2017.CSV", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')
NB_2018= pd.read_csv("E:/NB_2018.CSV", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')
```

and so on. I was wandering if there is a way to call the right dataframe just by having the year that I need, for example I tried:

```
year_needed = 2018
print("NB_"+str(year_needed)["col_needed"])
```

but I get the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Is there a way to access the dataframe just by having a piece of its name?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would be to store your `DataFrame`s in a dictionary, e.g.:

```
dfs = {
    2014: pd.read_csv("E:/NB_2014.CSV", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')
    2015: pd.read_csv("E:/NB_2015.CSV", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')
    2016: pd.read_csv("E:/NB_2016.CSV", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')
    2017: pd.read_csv("E:/NB_2017.CSV", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')
    2018: pd.read_csv("E:/NB_2018.CSV", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')
}
```

Then access, for example, using:

```
dfs[2018]
```

When you have a list of items like this which you would like to access by name, a dictionary-based approach is much preferred over `eval`, which is a [dangerous coding practice](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) and should not be considered when you know in advance how you will access the relevant `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use eval on python to transform string into code

```
print(eval('NB_' + str(year_needed) + '["col_needed"]' ))
```